# sum over partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{P}_{n,k}$ be the set of unordered partitions of a positive integer $n$ into $k$ parts $\mathbf{n}:=(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$, i.e. such that $n=n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k$.

Are there known results for the following quantity?

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mathbf{n}\in\mathcal{P}_{n,k}} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{n_j}
\end{equation}

And more in general for quantities such as

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mathbf{n}\in\mathcal{P}_{n,k}} \prod_{j=1}^k f(n_j),
\end{equation}

for some function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{N}$?

I am not familiar with results involving partitions so any insight on this will be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Partitions are unordered, e.g. $\mathcal{P}_{3,2}$ has only one element, that is $\{{2,1}\}$. I will edit my original question by specifying partitions are unordered.

Comment: Some related discussion (without $k$) is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178714/faster-formula-to-compute-sum-over-partitions