# Sum $f(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k) 1^{n_1} 2^{n_2} \ldots k^{n_k}$ over partitions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions, generating-functions

Use the notation $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k) \vdash n$ to denote that $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$ is a partition of the positive integer $n$, that is, $n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k = n$ and $n_1 \ge n_2 \ge \ldots \ge n_k \ge 1$. Let $f=f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ be a multivariate function of countably many arguments.

Is there a way to simplify the following generating function over partitions:
\begin{equation}\tag{$*$}
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k) \vdash n} f(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k) 1^{n_1} 2^{n_2} \ldots k^{n_k} \right) z^n,
\end{equation}
say, by making use of generating function of partition functions, or some magic identities in partition theory?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or references.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to @SamHopkins and @Gro-Tsen for their observations, I put the term $z^n$ in the summand which makes the sum $(*)$ the form of a generating function. Also thanks to @Gro-Tsen's hint, the sum $(*)$ can be simplified for a special class of $f$ by making use of the conjugation of partitions. Let $(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l)$ denote the [conjugate partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions) of $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$, that is, $n'_j := \# \{i: n_i\ge j \}$. Define
$$ \hat f(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l) := f(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k).$$
Then the sum $(*)$ becomes
\begin{equation}
(*) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l) \vdash n} \hat f(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l) n'_1! n'_2! \ldots n'_l! \right) z^n.
\end{equation}
Now if the new function $\hat f$ is a tensor power, that is,
$$ \hat f(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l) = a(n'_1) \ldots a(n'_l),$$
for some function $a$, then due to [the first comment of this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178714/faster-formula-to-compute-sum-over-partitions),
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
1+(*) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l) \vdash n} a(n'_1) n'_1! \ldots a(n'_l) n'_l! \right) z^n \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1- a(i) i! z^i}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
In the special case that $f\equiv 1$, we have $a=1$ and the resulting function is the generating function of the OEIS sequence [A077365](https://oeis.org/A077365). Another special case is that $a(i) = 1/i!$, where the resulting function is the [generating function of the basic partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Generating_function).

But what about the general case where $\hat f$ is not a tensor power, e.g., $\hat f$ is a general tensor product like $ \hat f(n'_1,n'_2,\ldots,n'_l) = a_1(n'_1) \ldots a_l(n'_l)$?

Comment: Do you know the answer (omitting the sum on $n$) for some special cases, like $f=1$ or $n_1+\cdots+n_k$ or $n_1\cdots n_k$? (Are the corresponding sequences of $n$ in the OEIS? If you don't know the answer offhand, searching for the numerical values there might be a start.) This might give a clue as to what can be hoped for in the general case.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you very much for your suggestion. To be honest, I don't know the answer for the case $f=1$. I'm really a beginner of combinatorics (even worse). I've been reading some books on combinatorics. But so far I didn't find something related to the summation in my question. Could you please provide a reference, say, for the special case that $f=1$?

Comment: No, I don't know! But I suggest you try computing the first few values and look them up in the OEIS, to see if this gives a known sequence. This might provide helpful pointers.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Very nice suggestion! Thank you! I found the sequence for the case $f=1$ in OEIS. It is [A077365](https://oeis.org/A077365). I'm trying to find more clues from this sequence.

Comment: @SamHopkins Or maybe there's a $z^n$ missing and what is meant is a generating function (which, for certain sufficiently rapidly decreasing $f$, might be evaluatable at $z=1$).

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, you are right. Thank you for reminding me. The generating function of [A077365](https://oeis.org/A077365) diverges for any nonzero $z$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Good point! That is indeed my original thinking. The function $f$ needs to have some fast decay.

Comment: @SamHopkins Maybe I should delete the confusing assumption that $f$ is symmetric, because $f$ is actually only defined on the set of non-increasing sequences. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: @SamHopkins I added a special case to the post. But I'm still wondering about the general case.

Comment: @Dreamer: Thanks! I deleted my other comments. It is much clearer to ask about the generating function, like you have now done.

Comment: Attaching some terminology to your question: The product $1^{n_1} \cdots k^{n_k}$ is called the norm of the partition by Robert Schneider and Andrew Sills in a 2020 paper (*Integers* [20A, A13](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/cgi-bin/get.cgi)).  You might look at it and the handful of papers that reference it.