# A $q$-series identity: proof request

Tags: nt.number-theory, power-series, q-identities

Denote the $q$-expressions $[q]_n=(1-q)\cdots(1-q^n)$ for $n\geq1$ and $[q]_0:=1$. Also, $[q]_{\infty}=(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)\cdots$.

> **QUESTION.** Is this identity true? It seems to be.
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{[q]_{\infty}}{[q]_n}\right)
> =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^k}{1-q^k}.$$

Comment: It is equivalent to Theorem 1 in [Wang Zheng Bing, Robbert Fokkink, Wan Fokkink, *A relation between partitions and the number of divisors*](https://www.cs.vu.nl/~wanf/pubs/partition.pdf). Indeed, $p\left(n\right)$ is the coefficient of $q^n$ on the left hand side of your identity, while $d\left(n\right)$ is the corresponding coefficient on the right hand side.

Comment: @darij grinberg This was proved earlier in Nathan Fine's book, "Basic Hypergeometric Series and Applications", AMS 1988. It is equation (12..45). Incidentally, parts of this chapter were distributed long before the book was published as the manuscript which was not widely circulated, but I don't have a copy of this manuscript to know if this identity was included.

Comment: In general I believe such kind of identities are called sums-of-tails identities. Just googling will give several really cute ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As darij grinberg says, the result is equivalent to the main result in the linked paper. On the right-hand side we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{q^k}{1-q^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (q^k + q^{2k} + \cdots ) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl( \sum_{d \mid n} 1 \bigr) q^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n) q^n $$

where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

For the left-hand side, observe that $-[q]_\infty/[q]_{m-1} = -(1-q^m)(1-q^{m+1}) \cdots $ is the generating function for partitions with distinct parts not less than $m$, counting partitions with an even number of parts with sign $-1$. Therefore in $\sum_{m=1}^\infty (1- [q]_\infty/[q]_{m-1})$, a partition with smallest part $b(\lambda)$ is counted precisely $b(\lambda)$ times, once in each of the first $b(\lambda)$ summands, and always with the same sign. Therefore for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the coefficient of $q^n$ in the left-hand side is

$$\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} (-1)^{\ell(\lambda)-1} b(\lambda). $$

By the [main result](https://www.cs.vu.nl/~wanf/pubs/partition.pdf) of Bing, Fokkink and Fokkink, this is $\tau(n)$. Since the constant terms on either side are $0$, this proves the identity.

*Remark.* A well-known recurrence for the partition function is $np(n) = \sum_{m < n} \sigma(m)p(n-m)$, where $\sigma$ is the sum of divisors function.  MacMahon published [two](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s2-19.1.305) [papers](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-19.1.75) in the 1920s with many related identities, replacing $\sigma(n)$ with $\sigma_s(n) = \sum_{d \mid m} d^s$. But I cannot find this result in his work.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Anyway, the "well-known recurrence" appears in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127000/partitions-sum-of-divisors-identity , where people have also asked about its provenance.